# Solution to use Azure DevOps SDK for Git functions

Tags: azure-devops

I am searching for a solution where I can use Azure DevOps SDK to view repositories, branch, commit, etc. like a Blazor or other .NET platforms like WinForm.

Before I start mucking with the SDK and create an application using the APIs, for example, I would rather purchase or use a solution that is already out there without re-inventing the wheel.

I would be interested in any solution that someone had already tried or a paid solution.

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am searching for a solution where I can use Azure DevOps SDK to view repositories, branch, commit

[List all repositories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) via Azure DevOps REST API

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=6.1-preview.1
```

List branch via repo name

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/{project name}/_apis/git/repositories/{repo name or repo ID}/refs?filter=heads&api-version=6.1-preview.1
```

[Retrieve git commits for a project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20commits?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits?api-version=6.1-preview.1
```

Comment: Thank you for the resource. I guess I have to code this on my own in a Blazor or ASP.NET application. I was hoping if there is something out there that someone has already done or selling.

Comment: Hi @JennyL, I found [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#assemble-the-request), it get a list of team projects in a Azure DevOps Services organization, you could refer to it to use the REST API with C# code.

Comment: Hi Vito, thank you for following up on this. The sample helped, but I ended up using the SDK in C#. I'm still struggling with it and I would still prefer a complete toolkit solution that I can use for this. The search goes on.